# conversion from rtf to docx from the commandline on a Mac in Python

Tags: python, macos, rtf, docx

Does anyone know of a Python script to convert rtf to docx on a Mac?

Textutil does not properly process headers and footers, so that is not an option. I need a commandline utility because I have a large number of files in different locations to process. The textutil interface is fine... it is just mind-boggling that it doesn't handle the header (which contains important information in my documents).

A Python script is preferable.

-Joe

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact answer to your question, but can suggest another way of doing it: Since you are doing this on OSX, why not use the built-in automator? For an example, look at http://aseriesoftubes.com/articles/how-to-batch-convert-doc-files-to-pdf-format-using-mac-osx-automator/ or https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3050596?tstart=0

Comment: I am familiar with automator. However, our files are distributed across a large filesystem (25,000 files spanning a large directory tree). I can generate a list of files to be converted from the command line into a text file. How do I import that text file into automator? Can I cut and paste?

Comment: You could symlink all of those files in a single folder, and then tell automator to process that folder.